# Render custom php template into string

Tags: plugins, templates

I have a native php template, say,

```
<div> <?= $data ?> </div>
```

Deeply inside the wordpress plugin page I need to render it into string. I feel I miss something well-known here, but currently I’m totally stuck with it.

I obviously tried

```
ob_start();
include('tmpl.php');
return ob_get_clean();
```

hack, but it seems to ruin the WP context. Is there any way to simply render the foreign template into string for the future use?

**Update**

In fact, there was another bug in the code inducing this error. `ob_start()`⇒`ob_get_clean()` works pretty fine as expected.

Comment: Aren't you missing an `echo`?. Also, that seems to be a template for some PHP framework.

Comment: @TomásCot That seems to be a very standard php syntax.

Comment: What do you mean with "ruins the WP context"? Explain a bit more what you are trying to do. Are you trying to include a WP template on a non-WordPress page? The other way around?

Comment: @guidod Well, apparently there was another bug in the code which in fact ruined the WP context. I’ll make an update in the question for late visitors.